# Mapping ViewModel to JS Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

Is there possible to map a model (server side) into JS object? The problem is that I can not return a json object from the server side.

View.cshtml:

```
@model TestModel

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function ($) {
        var jsObject = {
            Property1: @Model.Property1,
            Property2: @Model.Property2,
            Property3: @Model.Property3,
            ...
        };
    });
</script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: YOU CAN RETURN JSON  FROM SERVER SIDE

Comment: The problem is that I can't and this is the reason why I'm asking this :) just want to know if it's possible...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [**Json.Encode**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.json.encode%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) Method converts a data object to a string that is in the JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) format.

```
var jsObject = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))
```