# Casting MVC ViewModel to Javascript object in external .js file

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

As a corollary to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24493588/mapping-viewmodel-to-js-object), I know it's possible to represent cast an MVC ViewModel object to Javascript using some technique like `var jsObject = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))`.

I'm assuming it's only possible to use this technique directly on the actual `.cshtml` page.  What if I wanted to us this data in an external `.js` file?

If I instantiated `var jsObject` on the `.cshtml` page, could I still access this object from an external Javascript file, or would it be considered to be out-of-scope?

Comment: Use [RazorJS](http://www.nuget.org/packages/RazorJS)

Comment: Create Action and call it using jQuery ajax.

Comment: @Brij I'm looking for a way to do this without making another round-trip to the server. Also, RazorJS doesn't look like it's maintained (its website is down) and I'm not looking to use C#-style syntax in my Javascript files.

Comment: you would like to see http://techbrij.com/pass-session-viewbag-values-js-file-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could access the generated `jsObject` from within your javascript file. In order for it to not be out of scope, you need to treat it like a global:

In your `.cshtml':

```
var jsObject = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))
<script src="/path/to/jsFile.js">
```

Inside your `jsFile.js`

```
if(jsObject)
{
 // do whatever you need
}
```

Notice that since you are not passing in the variable to a method in `jsFile.js` the only way for `jsFile.js` to get access to it is by knowing what name you gave it in your `.cshtml`. This makes your code very brittle.
The other, better approach, is to pass in the variable to your JavaScript function.

In your `.cshtml`:

```
<script src="/path/to/jsFile.js">

var jsObject = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))
myProcessor(jsObject)
```

Using this approach, the `myProcessor` method doesn't care what the name of your variable is.